# Haskell -- How to split a number into a list for further processing?

Tags: haskell, numbers, split

I have an Int that i want to split into it's individual numbers  which ideally would be contained in a list, which i can then process further. So i would like something like this:

```
split 245
--will then get an list containing [2,4,5]
```

Is anyone familiar with such a function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
import Data.Char

map digitToInt $ show 245
```

Comment: Yes, if you want to use this approach... Just take care to pass in nonnegative numbers only. Otherwise you'd be passing a `'-'` to `digitToInt`, which is an error. Incidentally, John Boker's cool answer has a funkier issue with negative numbers... check it out. :-)

Comment: Yes, the basic idea of this is that you use "show" to convert 245 to a string, which is a list of characters. Then you map digitToInt over this list of characters, and you get digits in place of characters, so you have a list of digits.

Answer (score 4):

would the example here work for you ? http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/5961

```
convRadix :: (Integral b) => b -> b -> [b]
convRadix n = unfoldr (\b -> if b == 0 then Nothing else Just (b `mod` n, b `div` n))
```

example:

```
> convRadix 10 1234
[4, 3, 2, 1]
> convRadix 10 0
[]
> convRadix 10 (-1)
[9,9,...] (infinite)

to convert haskell radix by mokehehe on Thu Aug 21 08:11:39 -0400 2008
```

Comment: I'd write it more like `convRadix b = unfoldr mModDiv where mModDiv 0 = mzero; mModDiv n = let (q, r) = n \`divMod\` b in return (r, q)` (split across lines, which I can't do in a comment) but it's really all the same :)

Answer (score 2):

```
digits :: Int -> [Int]
digits 0 = []
digits n = digits k ++ [r]
    where k = div n 10; r = mod n 10
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and put four spaces at the beginning of each line, so it will be formatted as code.

Answer (score 1):

```
digits :: (Integral a) => a -> [a]
digits = flip digits' [] . abs

digits' :: (Integral a) => a -> ([a] -> [a])
digits' n = if q == 0
  then (r :)
  else (digits q ++) . (r :)
  where
    (q, r) = n `divMod` 10
```

---

```
digits   1234  == [1, 2, 3, 4]
digits (-1234) == [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Or `digits = fst . head . filter ((==) 0 . snd) . tail . iterate (\(d, n) -> let (q, r) = n \`divMod\` 10 in (r:d, q)) . (,) [] . abs` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
digits = reverse . map (`mod` 10) . takeWhile (> 0) . iterate (`div` 10) . abs
```